# installation stuck at detecting file system

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 (i386-32 bit) dual boot with Windows 7 (home premium 64 bit). I created a USB stick correctly, Checked for md5sum.

After manual option, I created swap, `/`, `/home` and proceeded. It gets stuck at `detecting file systems`.

I tried several times with following options:

1. enabling wifi (which kept loosing and searching for connection)
2. wired internet (worked fine (I hope) )
3. with out internet (I.e without updates)

P.S. I just now un-installed opensuse 11.3 from dual boot with Windows. The memory which was freed from suse is in free space (Light Green) and not unallocated (black). is that a problem?

Alongside I am searching for windows help to convert the green space to black.

[Screen shot of gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mWmP.jpg) from Try Ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried to create `/boot` and /swap? I'm not really sure but wouldn't hurt to try!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: Boot of an Ubuntu liveCD, use the "Try Ubuntu option", go to the dash (the upper left icon) type `gparted` and take a screenshot of that and post it somewhere and add the link into your question.  Please [edit] your question to add this information...

Comment: Thank you. Question edited with gparted information. (Sorry the pictures are taken from camera and are not the screenshots.)

Comment: 8 years later and still the same problems with Ubuntu. I'm so happy I don't need it really... Windows is sooooo easy compared to this sh...t!

Comment: I have faced the problem today and I have followed this complete feed and succeeded. I have unmounted my external hard drive first. And then I had gone for the `Ubuntu` installation by choosing my external hard drive in the installation wizard. Now, I am able to boot `Ubuntu` from my ***external hard disk***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I'd:

- Take a [full system backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)
- Download and burn a DVD of [14.04.2 32 bit version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) as you seem to have a need for OpenOCD which doesn't seem to like 64-bit versions.
- boot and follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu),
- at step 8 take "something else",
- delete the 200GB `/dev/sda6` partition and create a 32GB `/` and 128 GB `/home` in `ext4` format.
- leave the rest unallocated (to add to something when that one becomes full somewhere in the future)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. my motive for ubuntu was to use OpenOCD. OpenOCD doesnt work well on 64bit versions. Driver problems. so should i carry out this procedure with 32bit image? (i.e. instead of pen drive i'll use live cd).P.S. this partially answers the que, should i still tick & make it green?

Comment: There you go: edited.  Anything else not answered?

Comment: :) Happy... thnx i'll try and let you know... every thing answered... :D

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem as you when I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 16.10. It was always stuck on `Detecting file systems`. I found out that the installation program will try to umount the path `/isodevice`, but the file is held by kernel, so umount fails.

At last, I opened the terminal and ran the command

```
sudo umount -l /isodevice
```

with success. Then I ran the installation program again. The problem did not occur again.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to look for any mounted partitions by running `df`, and then for whatever items you see there that are partitions of the drive you're trying to install on, run `sudo unmount -l DEVIICE_NAME`, where DEVICE_NAME is the value in the first column of the output of of `df`

Answer (score -1):

If u stuck in detecting file ... ( cdrom failed )
Restart os , choose try ubuntu

1. sudo umount -l /isodevice ( terminal )
2. Reinstall ---> continue --> something else ( if u want to create manual partition )
3. just using your " free space " ( if it equal 0 , change from your disk NTFS ( sub it )
4. Finally , u will have free space create 3 partition ( swap , / , /home ) .
5. Choose your region time and the rest

Comment: duplicate of the accepted answer