# Taking more than two days for detecting file system during Ubuntu 16.10 installation

Tags: system-installation, filesystem

I had Windows 10 installed on my C drive. Then I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.10 from a pen drive. Installation steps are fine as I followed from a valid site. But, It is now more than 2 days in the "Detecting file systems" step. It is progressing as I can see from log. But, during the process I get warning messages like:

```
(warning) source id 575558 was not found when trying to remove it
GLib.source_remove(self.changed_row_id)
```

Should I stop the installation or wait?

Comment: Stop the installation. It's busted. Try restarting the installation.

Comment: @heynnema
What should I do to install it properly?

Comment: Edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of gparted and I'll take a look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installation stuck at detecting file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588036/installation-stuck-at-detecting-file-system)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my gaming PC.

In BIOS, after you select to boot with the live USB/CD, toggle to Try Ubuntu using arrow key, 
then press `e`.

Now-you will come upon the install command line; here -
append the text within the round brackets - `(acpi=off)` - after (quiet splash), 
then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue the booting process. 
You should not see this issue again.