# ubuntu install stuck on "detecting file systems"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

i've been trying to dual boot ubuntu and windows 10 but every ubuntu install i've tried leads to the same problem which is getting stuck on "detecting file systems". i'm using an external hdd. i've tried:

- rufus and etcher to flash the iso
- three different step by step guides
- multiple partition setups
- checking md5sums
- connecting to the internet
- changing boot order
- turning off secure boot
- different file systems while formatting
- installing to just the external drive instead of dual booting

computer specs:

- hp envy x360 laptop
- amd ryzen 3700u (x64)
- 16gb ram
- windows 10 home (64 bit)

i also keep getting a "failed to unmount /cdrom" error but i don't know if that's related.

i can provide any more detail that is needed. thank you for your time.

EDIT: all i had to do was type `acpi=off` in the terminal before i installed it. i got that answer from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473487/it-is-normal-ubuntu-installation-remain-in-detecting-file-systems-long?rq=1) forum.

Comment: Your question could be improved... Is this a boot failure or does the installer crash?

Comment: If you format for the install target, ALWAYS ext4 (except mac and windows, but thats for somewhere else)