# Ubuntu 22.04 USB Installation is stuck at detecting file systems and can't unmount /cdrom

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mount, live-usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 with an 8GB bootable USB.
I already tried to redo the steps and create a bootable USB again with Rufus and balenaEtcher. Likewise I'm trying to get dual boot of Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10 installed on my computer.

[image: installing alongside Windows boot manager]

I already did the partitions as you can see in GParted.

[image: here]

I'm stuck at detecting file systems

[image: detecting file systems]

and also I got the error of:

```
Failed to unmount partitions
The installer needs to commit changes to partition tables, but cannot do so because partitions on the following could not be unmounted.
/cdrom
Please close any applications using these mount points.
```

[image: failed to unmount partitions]

Also I already put the `acpi=off` as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473487/it-is-normal-ubuntu-installation-remain-in-detecting-file-systems-long).

[image: acpi=off]

My specs:

- System Manufacturer: HP
- System Model: HP Pavilion Notebook
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz 2.40 GHz
- Card: NVIDIA GeForce 940M
- RAM: 6.0 GB

[System information dxdiag.txt from windows10](https://gist.github.com/8fn/51744cc8860672f6659ebc0bdb4aaa59)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with an old release and i created an bootable usb with ubuntu 18.04. I installed it without any problems, seems like the problem was the ubuntu 22.04 iso but im not 100% sure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).